# Auto Create a task from a Gmail via filter label

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, google-tasks

Is there a way to label an Email w/the word task, email it to myself and have it added to my tasks list automatically.  I know I can open the email and add tasks but I'd like to do this via a filter rule.

Answer (score 5):

No, this isn't currently possible.  [(support posting)](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=6f86b35fb38b4e9a&hl=en)  The quickest way I've found is to create a filter that applies a label to these emails.  Then, I am able to open up the label, use keyboard shortcuts to navigate and open an email, and then `shift+t` will create a task for the opened email.  Use a keyboard shortcut to get to the next email, rinse and repeat.

If a filter action to add to tasks is ever created, I'll just have to switch my filter action rather than creating a setup then.